# alertmanager/tivoli/omibus IBM openshift

Tags: openshift, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager, tivoli

I have installed openshift v3.11 enviroment with prometheus stack as monitoring. 
Now, i have to foward the alerts from prometheus to Tivoli Omnibus. How can i do that? Any suggestions?
Tivoli has no rest api and can not manage webhooks.

BR

Comment: You can also use messagebus probe to consume rest apis. Omnibus 7.4+ has got rest api interface